# "A food is fed (to) someone or something" vs. "Someone or something is fed on (or with) a food"

Tags: grammar, american-english, word-usage

Focusing on the passive voice, which of the following grammatical constructions is (or are) more typical of AE?

> More research is necessary before ***soy formula is fed to babies^** [source](http://everydaylife.globalpost.com/long-term-consequences-formula-feeding-22685.html)
>
> More research is necessary before ***babies are fed on soy formula***.
>
> More research is necessary before ***babies are fed with soy formula***.
>
> More research is necessary before soy ***babies are fed soy formula***.

-

> Reductions in mother-to-child transmission are optimized when ***babies are fed on formula milk*** [source](http://www.sueholden.org.uk/publications/AIDS_on_the_Agenda.pdf)>/
>
> Reductions in mother-to-child transmission are optimized when ***formula milk is fed to babies***.
>
> Reductions in mother-to-child transmission are optimized when ***babies are fed with formula milk***.
>
> Reductions in mother-to-child transmission are optimized when ***babies are fed formula milk***.

.

> In the winter, certified organic ***fodder is fed to*** our Jersey and Guernsey cows.
>
> In the winter, our Jersey and Guernsey ***cows are fed on*** certified organic fodder.
>
> In the winter, our Jersey and Guernsey ***cows are fed with*** certified organic fodder.
>
> In the winter, our Jersey and Guernsey ***cows are fed*** certified organic fodder is fed.

.

> This ensures that a clean supply of ***ink is fed to*** your printer every time.
>   [source](http://continuousink.com/support-a-knowledge-base/frequently-asked-questions)>/
>
> This ensures that your ***printer is fed on*** a clean supply of ink every time. (sounds weird).
>
> This ensures that your ***printer is fed with*** a clean supply of ink every time.
>
> This ensures that your ***printer is fed*** a clean supply of ink every time.

Comment: Not "fed on", just fed.  **"Reductions in mother-to-child transmission are optimized when babies are fed formula milk."**

Comment: Wait - this title has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Oldcat How could you tell?  I would need a both hands and a compass to try to parse that!

Comment: Well, everything was different back then. Question and Title.

Comment: Can I vote that this question be set on fire?

Comment: @Oldcat If I asked this question, it's because I remember reading in a reference book several years ago that the grammatical turn "something is fed to someone" was preferred in AE (i.e. chiefly AE) to "someone is fed with something", so I just meant to check if there was any accuracy to this.

Comment: **Please** try to get your questions into a more-or-less final state **before** posting them, rather than editing them repeatedly after posting. It's tough to answer a moving target, and again there's a risk of flipping the Community Wiki switch by editing too often.

Comment: Your subject line is atrocious. Please get rid of those bizarro abbreviations, and focus your question. It is not answerable, nor even readable, in its current form.

Comment: @NourishedGourmet - you asked one question about feeding cows, edited it into a second different one about babies, and then a third about who knows what each larger than before. Titles did not match the subject.  So which *this question* do you mean?

Comment: @Oldcat Question is focused on "something is fed to someone or something (can be an animal, a printer, etc.)" vs. "someone or something (can be an animal, a printer, etc.)is fed "on", or "with", or "nix" something. I just want to know which one of these passive constructions is more typical of modern day AE. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In the first part of your tryptich, I favor number three,**

> Reductions in mother-to-child transmission are optimized when babies are fed formula milk.

But coming in a close second is

> Reductions in mother-to-child transmission are optimized when babies are fed with formula milk.

Frankly, I prefer getting rid of the passive "are fed" and "are fed with" by wording the sentence as follows:

> We reduce mother-to-child transmissions optimally by feeding babies formula milk.

Or,

> We reduce mother-to-child transmissions optimally when we feed babies formula milk.

Or,

> Optimally, by feeding babies formula milk we reduce mother-to-child transmissions.

**As for the middle part of your tryptich, I like number two**,

> In the winter, our Jersey and Guernsey cows are fed with certified organic fodder.

However, I would prefer it read as follows:

> In the winter, we feed our Jersey and Guernsey cows certified organic fodder.

**Now for the last part of your tryptich. I think I prefer number three,**

> This ensures that the printer is fed with a clean supply of ink every time.

And believe it or not, it sounds just fine, as is, since the feeding is done mechanically, I assume, by some built-in device and not a human being. If so, then the word *This* could precede the name of the device; for example,

> "This *auto-feed device* ensures that the printer is fed with a clean supply of ink every time."

(By the way, I was brought up in Rochester, a decent size city in Upstate New York, near Lake Ontario, one of the Great Lakes, the names of which you can remember by using the acronym/mnemonic  H.O.M.E.S., which stands for Lakes Huron, Ontario, Michigan, Erie, and Superior.)

Comment: Thank you for your contribution to my question. I know the active is generally a better choice than the passive. The thing is I remember reading from an authoritative source several years ago that the grammatical phrasing "something is fed to someone or something" was preferred in AE (chiefly AE) to the other passive constructions listed in the OP. Hence my question. :)

Comment: @NourishedGourmet: You're welcome, I'm sure. My only criterion for choosing my favorite sentences was, simply, which ones sounded best or most natural to me. The authority to whom you refer may be correct. Don't be hesitant to include that authority as a hyperlink in your question. If you are not sure how to provide a link in a question, let me know; it's really quite simple. Don

Answer (score 1):

Outside of Academia and Management, active voice is more common than passive voice.

Comment: Passive voice is commonly used in many disciplines, including scientific and technical writing, when the writer wishes to emphasize the recipient of the action over the actor.

Comment: which is why I excluded academia and management.